# Attempting to trap window message in VB.NET DLL

Tags: vb.net, windows, message

I am trying to intercept a windows message sent using the WINAPI function "BroadcastSystemMessage" (from an XLL that sends this message when a new workbook is created).

I've attempted to use two methods to do this, but each has its disadvantages:

1) Using a managed listening window:

However, I don't want to run the risk of the user ever closing this listening window and,

```
listenForm.Show()
listenForm.visible = false
```

seems sloppy.

2) Using hooks:

However, the call back for "SetWindowsHookEx" only has a few parameters:

```
Protected Function HookCallBack(code As Integer, wParam As IntPtr, lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
```

and I'm looking for a way to access the "msg" struct which has the information I registered with "RegisterWindowMessage".

Here, "lParam" points to this struct and I can use:

```
Dim output(100) As Byte
Marshal.Copy(e.lParam, output, 0, 100)
```

to dereference this pointer. I have no idea how to parse the result, and it also bothers me that I'm wandering so far from the managed universe.

My question: can the down sides to each way be fixed, and what is the standard way to intercept messages or do something like this?

Comment: I'm not necessarily saying it's good or bad but creating a hidden window for this purpose is pretty common practice. You can size the window very small and you can move it outside the screen bounds to make sure users can't close it.

Comment: Got it, going with that then, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Show() method call is just one of the ways to get the native window created.  You can also simple create it yourself in the constructor:

```
Public Sub new
    InitializeComponent()
    Me.CreateHandle()
End Sub
```

Or if you cannot avoid the Show() call because it is the startup form of your app then do it like this:

```
Protected Overrides Sub SetVisibleCore(value As Boolean)
    If Not Me.IsHandleCreated then
        value = False
        Me.CreateHandle()
    End If
    MyBase.SetVisibleCore(value)
End Sub
```

Note that in neither case the Load event will fire so move any code you have there into the constructor of the form class.

---

Do not use a window hook, all you have to do is override the WndProc() subroutine to see broadcasted messages:

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
    If m.Msg = theRegisteredMessage Then
        '' etc...
    End If
    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub
```

Do favor a plain SendMessage() with HWND_BROADCAST over BroadcastSystemMessage().  Or better yet, a Socket so you don't have to yell so loud.

Comment: Thanks as usual for a helpful answer Hans.

Comment: Hans, I have another question about best practices if you'll indulge me. The method which uses this listening window lives in a dll and is not a form based application; it is meant to late bind to Excel once Excel is ready. I am currently running this listening window in a new thread using .showdialog(). Is there a more natural way to launch the listening window that doesn't require it to appear at all?